# (SystemJS) Provider parse errors:(…) With angular2-in-memory-web-api

Tags: angular

Trying to get angular2-in-memory-web-api working with my project. Made progress but now getting (SystemJS) Provider parse errors:(…). 
Seems straight forward not sure what I'm missing , everything compiles, I'm not getting any 404's so I know all is ended up in the /dist..

Sorry about the formatting

```
Package.json   

  {
    "name": "crestron-hydrogen",
    "version": "v1.0.3",
    "scripts": {
      "tsc": "tsc",
      "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
      "lite": "lite-server",
      "postinstall": "npm run typings install",
      "start": "gulp serve",
      "typings": "typings",
      "test": " \"karma start karma.conf.js\" ",
      "test-once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
      "gulp": "gulp"
    },
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
      "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
      "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
      "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
      "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
      "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
      "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
      "angular2-busy": "1.0.2",
      "angular2-i18next": "0.0.59",
      "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.21",
      "core-js": "2.4.1",
      "i18next": "3.4.1",
      "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "1.0.0",
      "i18next-xhr-backend": "1.1.0",
      "ng2-completer": "0.2.3",
      "primeng": "1.0.0-beta.17",
      "primeui": "4.1.15",
      "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
      "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
      "systemjs": "0.19.39",
      "ts-smart-logger": "0.0.4",
      "zone.js": "0.6.23"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
      "browser-sync": "2.16.0",
      "concurrently": "2.0.0",
      "del": "2.2.2",
      "gulp": "3.9.1",
      "gulp-flatten": "0.2.0",
      "gulp-sourcemaps": "1.6.0",
      "gulp-typescript": "3.0.2",
      "gulp-uglify": "2.0.0",
      "gulp-zip": "3.2.0",
      "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
      "karma": "1.2.0",
      "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
      "karma-cli": "0.1.2",
      "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
      "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
      "typescript": "1.8.10",
      "typings": "1.3.0"
    }
  }
```

System.js

```
    (function(global) {

   // map tells the System loader where to look for things
      var map = {
        'app':  'app',
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-            browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-    dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',


        'portalservice-devices': 'http://portalservice-    devices.azurewebsites.net/app/boot.js',
    'portalservice-groups': 'http://portalservice-    groups.azurewebsites.net/app/boot.js',
        'portalservice-template': 'http://portal-service-    template.azurewebsites.net/app/boot.js',

        'proxyservice-devices': 'http://localhost:3001/app/boot.js',
        'proxyservice-groups': 'http://localhost:3002/app/boot.js',
        'proxyservice-template': 'http://localhost:3003/app/boot.js',

        'rxjs':              'node_modules/rxjs',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        '@angular':     'node_modules/@angular',
        'primeng':       'node_modules/primeng',
        'jssha':            'node_modules/jssha/src', 
        'ts-smart-logger': 'node_modules/ts-smart-logger', 
        'angular2-i18next': 'node_modules/angular2-i18next',

        'i18next': 'node_modules/angular2-    i18next/node_modules/i18next/i18next.min.js',
    'i18next-xhr-backend': 'node_modules/angular2-i18next/node_modules/i18next-    xhr-backend/i18nextXHRBackend.min.js', 

        'ts-metadata-helper': 'npm:ts-metadata-helper',
        'angular2-dynamic-component': 'npm:angular2-dynamic-component',
        'angular2-busy': 'npm:angular2-busy',
        'ng2-completer': 'npm:ng2-completer/bundles',
      };

      // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no     extension
      var packages = {
        'app':                            { main: 'boot.js',  defaultExtension:         'js' },
    'rxjs':                           { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'primeng':                        { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'jssha': { main: 'sha512.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }, 
        'ts-smart-logger': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-i18next': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'i18next': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'i18next-xhr-backend': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'ts-metadata-helper': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-dynamic-component': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-busy': { main: './index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },

        'ng2-completer': { main: 'ng2-completer.js', format: 'cjs' } 
      };

      var config = {
            defaultJSExtensions: true,
            map: map,
            packages: packages,
            paths: {
              // paths serve as alias
          'npm:': './node_modules/'
                }
     }

  // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
  if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

Comment: can you fix your formatting and provide the specific error you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

The name of the package changed. Update to `"angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.1.14"` now that you are using `@angular/* 2.*`

Comment: Ok trying 0.1.14 with new name .. Now I get the following error, tsc
node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-backend.service.d.ts(1,1): erro
r TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'core-js'.

Comment: Googled that error , removed reference to core in in-memory-backend.service.d.ts  then changed systemJs reference to 'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js', Back to square one (SystemJS) Provider parse errors:(…) *sigh*

Comment: Don't use 0.1.14. there is a regression bug. Use 0.1.13

Comment: 1.1.13 same error Provider parse errors. Seems like something else is the cause.